# XAMPP cannot display my web server while internet is not connected

Tags: php, browser, xampp, localhost

Recently I tried to access my localhost, my PHP doesn't display in any browser. But it display when I connect to the internet. Before, I have no problem to access my localhost while connected to the internet or not.

I tried to turn off my windows firewall (even I don't know it is related or not) and I also tried to put this function to see the error message. But nothing changes. The problem still exist.

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: 1. Please show us your **full** and **real** code 2. Do you have short open tags turned on? 3. xampp started ? 4. How does your url in the browser looks? 5. Where did you saved your file and with which extension ?

Comment: Have you checked whether xampp is started?

Answer (score 0):

I already fix my problem.
first, i replace all php tag `<?`
with the clear one `<?php`
Second, i check the port using cmd as administrator and type `netstat -a` and `netstat -b`

Even I don't know what's the difference between